# How to create spring boot jar package with testng test case and how can i run the testng test cases using the testng sute.xml from spring boot jar

Tags: spring-boot, selenium, testng

I have created a spring boot application, in which i have added the selenium and testng to test the application. Now i want to deploy the jar on remote machine and run the selenium Testng test cases and get the result.